# TFTP Client that include blksize option

Tags: networking, tftp

This question probably isn't Ubuntu specific, but I figured I'd ask in here since that's what I'm on.
I'm trying to test TFTP transfers with different block sizes, but it seems every tftp client I load does not have the blksize option.
Most of what I've managed to find relates to setting the block size on the server, which I have covered.  I did find some old BSD man pages that reference blksize as a client option, but again, the clients I've downloaded don't seem to have that option.

```
tftp> ?
Commands may be abbreviated.  Commands are:

connect         connect to remote tftp
mode            set file transfer mode
put             send file
get             receive file
quit            exit tftp
verbose         toggle verbose mode
trace           toggle packet tracing
status          show current status
binary          set mode to octet
ascii           set mode to netascii
rexmt           set per-packet retransmission timeout
timeout         set total retransmission timeout
?               print help information
tftp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this could be considered an answer...
I found "[atftp](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/atftp.1.html)" as an alternative to the standard tftp client.  It includes the blksize option, among other things.